# use with two static function in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, location, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

i have a table with Branch of business

i have the location of the Branches in the table

and i have a tags for the Branch

how i can do somthing like that:

```
Branch::withTag('electrician')
->DB::select("SELECT * FROM
                        (SELECT id, business_id, latitude, longitude, (3959 * acos(cos(radians('$lat')) * cos(radians(latitude)) *
                        cos(radians(longitude) - radians('$lng')) +
                        sin(radians('$lat')) * sin(radians(latitude))))
                        AS distance
                        FROM MySite.branches) AS distances

                    WHERE distance < '$max_distance' * 1.609344
                    ORDER BY distance;");
```

its not work
i try to show only the branches Around the loction :latitude, longitude only with the Tags that igive in the start

how i get the Branch with the tag i whant
and after that do only in the Result the location order ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can't use two static functions in the same command.
Answering your question: why don't you union the queries? `select()` is a Laravel [`Query Builder`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#selects)

```
Branch::withTag('electrician')->select("your query here");
```

Comment: its not work becuse i take the branches from FROM MySite.branches (from the table) but is not get the list of branches after a filter of the Tag that i do